# Select value and put as/alias variable name?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Based on the example below, I need to custom header column name based on the variable value. Is there a way to do this? Thank you.

```
DECLARE @date DATE
SET @date = '2020-10-2'

DECLARE @monthperYear DECIMAL
SET @monthperYear =  (SELECT ((cast (month(@date) as INT) / 12.0) * 100))

DECLARE @yearBefore INT
SET @yearBefore = (SELECT (year(@date) -1))

DECLARE @percentageheadername VARCHAR (30)
SET @percentageheadername =(SELECT CAST (@monthperYear as varchar(5))+ '% Full Year ' + CAST (@yearBefore as CHAR (5)) +'Actual' as percentageHeadername)



Create Table #sample
(
name varchar (50)
, percentage DECIMAL (10,2)
)

INSERT INTO #sample
(name, percentage)
VALUES
('Marcus', '8'), ('John', '70')

select name, **percentage as @percentageheadername** from #sample
DROP TABLE #sample
```

Comment: Why do it in SQL? Do it in your front end when you display it. You end up with very complex SQL for something that you shouldn't really be doing in SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use dynamic sql

```
set @percentageheadername = 'SomeName'
set @sqlCommand = 'select name, percentage as ' + @percentageheadername + ' from #sample'

EXEC (@sqlCommand)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use dynamic sql to execute your final query.

Query:

```
  DECLARE @date DATE
     SET @date = '2020-10-2'
     
     DECLARE @monthperYear DECIMAL
     SET @monthperYear =  (SELECT ((cast (month(@date) as INT) / 12.0) * 100))
     
     DECLARE @yearBefore INT
     SET @yearBefore = (SELECT (year(@date) -1))
     
     DECLARE @percentageheadername VARCHAR (30)
     SET @percentageheadername =(SELECT CAST (@monthperYear as varchar(5))+ '% Full Year ' + CAST (@yearBefore as CHAR (5)) +'Actual' as percentageHeadername)
                      
     Create Table #sample
     (
     name varchar (50)
     , percentage DECIMAL (10,2)
     )
     
     INSERT INTO #sample
     (name, percentage)
     VALUES
     ('Marcus', '8'), ('John', '70')
     
     declare @sql varchar(500)
                         
     SET @SQL = 'select name, percentage  ['+@percentageheadername +'] from #sample'
      
     EXEC (@SQL)
     
     DROP TABLE #sample
```

Output:

| name | 83% Full Year 2019 Actual |
| --- | --- |
| Marcus | 8.00 |
| John | 70.00 |

*db<fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=bfea02502dc68bd4fdaf180f23e8b63d)*